# html2pdf page number

Tags: html2pdf

I've got a html code and when I convert it to pdf using html2pdf, it is longer than a single page, and I need to put the page number in both pages.

I've tried putting the page_footer code as it is said in this post: [html2pdf page numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386599/html2pdf-page-numbering)

but it only shows the page number in the last page, not in the first one. I can modify the html code, but I understand that if I put the  tag at the end of it, html2pdf thinks that it refers to the end of the code, not the end of the page.

How can I put the page number in all the pages, from the first one to the last?

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can put the attribute `footer="page"` in the `<page>` tag and all the pages will be auto-numbered.

```
<page footer="page">
    <page_header>
        /* Page Header */
    </page_header> 
    <page_footer>
        /* Page Footer */
    </page_footer>

    /* Page Content */
</page>
```

[html2pdf:en:v4:page](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf%3aen%3av4%3apage)

Comment: do you know uif i can reset the page number in the next pages?